# Сортировка по значению в связи Laravel

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как отсортировать по значению в связи `products` ?

```
public function show(Branch $branch)
{
    
    return (new BranchResource($branch->load(['products.pays','programms','dopproducts', 'halls'])))
            ->response()
            ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

Вот какие данные приходят, сортировать `products` нужно по `price_new`

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Академия футбола Одесса",
  "adress": "Проспект Добровольського, 122/2",
  "phone": "+38 (067) 654-23-54",
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Полная оплата",
      "price_new": 300,
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "40/30/30",
      "price_new": 200,
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "50/50",
      "price_new": 100,
    }
  ],
  "programms": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Вперед до зірок",
      "branch_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-05-20 18:33:12",
      "updated_at": "2020-05-22 23:39:30"
    }
  ],
  "dopproducts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "branch_id": 1,
      "name": "Индивидуальная тренировка",
      "price": 300,
      "created_at": "2020-06-18 21:11:42",
      "updated_at": "2020-06-18 21:11:42"
    }
  ],
  "halls": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "branch_id": 1,
      "name": "Крытое поле клуба",
      "created_at": "2020-06-18 21:11:14",
      "updated_at": "2020-06-18 21:11:14"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Здесь все просто - решает `join`. Если бы предоставил схему данных и по какому полю сортировать, мог бы ответ написать

Comment: Дополнил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Итак, чтобы подгруженные связи отсортировать на стадии БД, надо использовать анонимную функцию для кастомизации запроса https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

```
public function show(Branch $branch)
{
    $branch->load([
        'products' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('price_new');
        },
        'products.pays',
        'programms',
        'dopproducts', 
        'halls'
    ]));
    return (new BranchResource($branch)
            ->response()
            ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

Comment: Первую версию вопроса не понял.